# Fullcalendar - adding nice alerts to cells when and event is dropped

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, popover

Currently, when dropping an event inside a cell, I'm doing the following:

```
eventDrop: function( event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view )
{
     alert ("event dropped in different cell");
}
```

This code pops up a simple alert.

However, I would like to add a nicer alert dialog (perhaps Bootstrap Popover?)
Any idea on how to achieve  that ?

Note, my events already have bootstrap popover which pops when clicking an event.
I need to have a different popover (different look&content) for the drop event.

Perhaps I should set the popover on the cell ?  How can I achieve that ?

Will appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate to the Bootstrap popover would be the Bootstrap Alert..

**JS**

```
$(".alert").delay(200).addClass("in").fadeOut(4000);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="alert alert-danger fade">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
      <strong>Alert!</strong> Here is my message..
</div>
```

[**Working Demo**](http://bootply.com/61025)

Otherwise, you could use the Popover and simply change its content.